# Name of Text Input is Undefined when added through PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have form that allows user to specify how many fields that they want and base on that input create those fields. However, when I run it, i get the error `Undefined index: lo`. `lo` is the name i gave the input field.
However, when I submit, the values are recorded into my database.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Unit Learning Outcomes</legend>
        Learning Outcome(s): <input type="number" name="number" /> <button type="submit" name="row">Go</button>
        </br>
        <?php           
            if(isset($_POST['row']))
            {
                $num = $_POST['number'];
                for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
                {
                    $j = $i;

                    echo "</br></br><input type='text' name='lo[]' placeholder='Learning OutCome ". ++$j ."'/>";

                }
            }
        ?>
        </br></br>

    </fieldset>
```

This is where I try to get the value entered in `lo`:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","assignment1");
$alert = 0;
$counter = 0;

if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
    $ucode = $_POST['ucode'];
    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    $aim = $_POST['aim'];
    $lo = $_POST['lo'];

foreach($lo as $loutcome)
        {
            if($loutcome=='')
            {
                $counter++;
            }
        }

        if($counter>3)
        {
            echo "Please Enter at least 2 Learning Outcomes</br>";
            $alert++;   
        }
```

store ti database:

```
foreach($lo as $loutcome)
        {
            $store = "INSERT INTO unitlo(UnitCode,LearningOutcome) VALUES('$ucode','$loutcome')";
            mysqli_query($db, $store);
            mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM unitlo WHERE LearningOutcome=''");
        }
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen got it, removed parts I found irrelevant though it still seems alot

Comment: Did you try to execute the same query into `PHPMyAdmin` query panel with some data and get the same result ? @Ned

Comment: What is `UnitCode` field type?